# Numeric methods?

Tags: numerical-methods

I would please like to receive advice on the following:

Prove that the given equation has a real solution, then find it, numerically;

$2^x-x^2=20$

I don't know how to do this...any help?

Comment: What methods have you learned? Fixed Point, Newton...

Comment: None...they just threw it at us

Answer (score 2):

You can use Newton's Method or other [*Root Finding Algorithms*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm).

The Newton iteration is given by:

$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \dfrac{f(x)}{f'(x)} = x_n - \dfrac{-x_n^2+2^{x_n}-20}{\ln(2) 2^{x_n}-2 x_n}$$

Choose:

- $x_0 = 0$
- $x_1 = x_0 - \dfrac{-x_0^2+2^{x_0}-20}{2^{x_0} \ln(2)-2 x_0} = 27.4112$
- $\ldots$
- $x_9  =  5.720341634024867$

Comment: how did you do it so quickly?

Comment: every stage gives you more accuracy ? are all solutions valid? I was told two places after decimal point...

Comment: This is a tough question. You have all sorts of things that can go wrong with these methods (machine precision, rounding, division by small numbers..). If you were told to use two, do it manually and round to two decimal places and see if you get eh same result. I used much more than that and strange things can happen when you do not. Starting from $x_0 = 0.00$, you will get the following iterates $0.00, 10.00, 8.69, 7.51, 6.56, 5.96, 5.74, 5.72$. That is still decent.

Comment: I used bisection it got me to around 5.75

Comment: That works as different methods will have slightly different results.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x) = 2^x - x^2 - 20$.

$x$ satisfies $f(x) = 0$ if and only if your equation is satisfied.

$f(x)$ is a continuous function, so you can apply the Intermediate Value Theorem:

Since $f(0) = 1 - 0 - 20 < 0$ and $f(10) = 1024 - 100 - 20 > 0$ so the theorem tells you that $f$ has a root between $0$ and $10$.

See [Bisection Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) which uses this idea to approximate the root or [Newton's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) which is more sophisticated.

Comment: I understand that this explanation only refers to the proof part, right? Also, how do you know it's continuous?

Comment: @Bak1139:   Polynomials and powers are continuous, and sums and differences of continuous functions are continuous.

Comment: @Bak1139: bisection method and Newton's method are algorithms for computing roots. I included links.

Comment: @RossMillikan how about continuous+not continuous?

Comment: @Bak1139:  Adding a non continuous function to a continuous function results in a non continuous function.  But it is possible to add two non continuous functions and get a continuous one.